# independent publisher/subscriber in different threads via rabbitmq in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, rabbitmq, message-queue, eventmachine

I need to implement independent publisher/subscriber via rabbitmq in rails (plann to use `amqp` [gem](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/amqp/)), but I need publisher work with one thread, subscriber works in another and they not depend from each other.

Currenlty i'm using `amqp gem` but it needs that messages sended and cunsumed inside single `eventmachine` code block. So my question is how to avoid it and make it completely independent?

Comment: You got solution for this? I am having same issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the possible variant for that is run subscriber and consumer in different **process** (not thread)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DDS for this section. Different process/application can be communicate using Data Distribution Service. 
[Object management Groups/Check this link](http://portals.omg.org/dds/)